# Elementary question in proof of uncountability of reals in Munkres topology

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to understand a proof of uncountability of reals given in Topology by Munkres, and I got stuck at one point which may be simple, but I couldn't justify its truth.

> Let $X$ be non empty compact Hausdorff, with no isolated points (i.e. no singleton set is open). Then $X$ is uncountable.

Let $U$ be non empty open. Choose $y$ in $U$ different from $x$ (possible by hypothesis).

Choose disjoint open sets $W_1$, $W_2$ containing $x, y $ respectively.

Then Munkres asserts that the **closure** of $W_2\cap U$ does not contain $x$, and I didn't understand why this is true in the case when $x$ belongs to $U$?

(See p. 176, Theorem 27.7)

Comment: It’s because $x\in W_1$ which is open and disjoint from $W_2$.

Comment: I edited partially concerning above replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $x \in \overline{W_2 \cap U}$, then for every open neighborhood of $x$, $V$, we'd have $V \cap W_2 \cap U \neq \emptyset$.

Choose $V = W_1$ to get a contradiction.